# Read word doc app crashing after 100+ files

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a procedure which I borrowed and modified shown below.  Basically the problem is that after some amount of files, the program will crash.  I traced it to this procedure.  Inevitably the document itself proved to be fine, so it is something about the repeated opening and closing of word docs which is causing issues.  And it's random, sometimes it will process 100 files, sometimes 800.  Anyone have any thoughts?  When I run it in the debugger I do not see any errors generated.  The program just stops processing files and becomes unresponsive. Is there some garbage collection that I am missing?  How can I tell if there is a memory leak?

```
 private string readFileContent(string path)
 {
    string docstring = "";

    Word.ApplicationClass wordApp = new Word.ApplicationClass();
    object file = path;
    object nullobj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(
      ref file, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
      ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
      ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
      ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);

    try
    {
        SProc.Println("Created word doc instance");
        //doc.Clipboard.Clear();
        doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
        doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
        SProc.Println("Copied text to clipboard");
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        docstring = data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
        txtFileContent.Text = docstring;
    }
    catch ( ConfigurationErrorsException e)
    {
            SProc.Println("Word Error:" +e.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
            doc.Close(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
            wordApp.Quit(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
    }
    return docstring;
 }
```

Comment: "And it's random":  Thinks: "wonder if it has anything to do with that commented out System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);  line....'

Comment: Rob: it's never a good sign when people post code with commented out lines and no explanation.

Comment: Why did you comment out the code that cleared the clipboard before you copied the text in the document?

Comment: The timer comment out was for a downstream app, it was a hack to force the word file to finish being read otherwise the downstream app would not work.  Not related.  The clipboard comment out was from the original code and would not compile.  The right code is this:  data.SetData(DataFormats.Text, true, "");  Moving the wordApp instance creation to a static member of a class did the trick.  Not only it is 10x or 100x faster, there are no more crashes.  Can not believe I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another suggestion:

Create the Word.ApplicationClass once and use it for the life of your application, I doubt you really want to start it and close it 800 times for 800 files.